# Typescript - Override Library Prototype Function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to override two different methods that are in a 3rd party library (vis.js) inside of an Angular 8 app.

Currently I'm importing the library like this:

```
import {Timeline, DataSet, TimelineTimeAxisOption, Graph2dOptions} from 'vis-timeline';
```

There are two functions on a new Timeline object:

```
const timeline = new Timeline(container, items, options);
```

```
timeline.timeAxis.step.prototype.getLabelMajor
timeline.timeAxis.step.prototype.getLabelMinor
```

However, I'm unable to get it to override them and not even sure how to do it at this point.